# Можно ли в redis хранить данные безопасно?

Tags: кэширование, redis, backend

Допустим есть веб-сервис где большое количество данных передаётся, можно ли для лучшей работы их передавать в redis, но условие что бы это было защищено?

Comment: вот есть интересная статья. https://habr.com/ru/post/178525/ при желании можно конечно защитить, но в общем то вопрос цены. сколько отдельных серверов вы готовы поставить в качестве хранилищ

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: - Что значит "`для лучшей работы`" ? 
 - Что значит "`защищено`" ?

Comment: Имеется ввиду что бы никто не смог подключится к redis серверу, и считать от туда данные.